# QGIS rule based symbology best way to only display the right attributes

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, rule

I have a layer with multiple columns that users need to toggle on and off for different maps/visualizations

In the example below, I want to show different colors by using the planner, and a different set of colors using the phase. I need to exclude features that have these fields null and I need a quick way of toggling them on and off.

Problem is, in order to make the groups like these, I have to make the parent transparent. This works fine if it's just for visualization, but doesn't work when people try to select features as these are still rendered, just transparent. This misleads people into only seeing 20 dots on the map but then when using the selection there are 100.

In this example, the "parent"  Planner and Phase are fully transparent whereas the "secondary" ones are different shapes and colors. In other words, if I only have Phase and Phase 1 toggled, I do not want to see Phase 2 or the other phases

[image]

How to be able to group features under the rule based styling, but then not render features on the "secondary" condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you double click on the "parent" group (`planner`,`Phase`), you can then un-tick the `symbol` checkbox, so the parent won't be rendered at all.

[image]